# mysql nested query - Top Three Salaries

Tags: mysql, nested

Please help me with this issue. There are 2 tables: Employee and Department tables.

correct:

```
select d1.name Department, e1.name Employee, e1.salary Salary 
from Employee e1, Department d1
where e1.departmentId = d1.id
and
e1.salary in (
    select * from (
        select distinct e2.salary 
        from Employee e2
        where e2.departmentid = e1.departmentid
        order by e2.salary desc limit 3
    ) as t)
```

why cant I write this query like this?

```
select d1.name Department, e1.name Employee, e1.salary Salary 
from Employee e1, Department d1
where e1.departmentId = d1.id
and
e1.salary in (
    select * from (
        select e2.departmentId, distinct e2.salary 
        from Employee e2
        group by e2.departmentId 
        order by e2.salary desc limit 3
    ) as t)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

The first problem in your query is that DISTINCT is a query modifier. You can only use it immediately after SELECT. DISTINCT applies to all columns in the select-list, not just one. So it makes no sense to put it before a single column.

The second problem is that you are comparing a single column to a subquery, so the subquery must return a single-column result. Each element returned by the subquery must be comparable to the left operand.

You can see this in regular IN() expressions too. The following is fine:

```
mysql> select 1 in (1, 2, 3) as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

But if you try to make each element of the list a tuple, these can't be compared to the left operand:

```
mysql> select 1 in ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'));
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

But if the left operand also is a tuple of the same degree, it's comparable:

```
mysql> select (1, 'a') in ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')) as ok;
+----+
| ok |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! (my previous comment got deleted).